# Angular 2 Change route (URL) and Load data from DB

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

In my project I have menu which is inside *ngFor loop and where I have menu.Id as a parameter to load data from database

```
<li *ngFor="let item of menu">
  <a [routerLink]="['/products', item .Id]">{{item .Name}}</a>
</li>
```

when I click this menu item for first time (no matter which one) it works great but after that to click another menu item it not works because `ProductsComponent` is already loaded and cann't take Id again (route isn't changed '/products/:id' Id is different but constructor is already loaded and component is initialized).

In `ProductsComponent`s' constructor getting data like this

```
 this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.menuId = params.menuId;
 });
```

- How do I can load data dynamically based on route?
- and is it possible to hide menu.Id in route?

Comment: Can you show your routing module?

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the info you need from the route on load

For example, in your ngOnInit you can call getMenuId() with the function:

```
getMenuId() {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('menuId');
    //do something with menuId, like call another function to load your data with the id
  }
```